# mysqli prepared - store results into array?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to optimize this section of code a bit to use an array such as $_SESSION['user']= $arr;.

```
// Store user db info in session for use
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,user,pass,email,timezone,lastIP,currIP,dtLastLogin,dtCurrLogin FROM test_users WHERE user = ?");
// bind params
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
// execute prepared statement
$stmt->execute();
// Bind result variables
$stmt->bind_result($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['pass'], $_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['timezone'], $_SESSION['lastIP'], $_SESSION['currIP'], $_SESSION['dtLastLogin'], $_SESSION['dtCurrLogin']); 
// fetch values
$stmt->fetch();     
// close statement
$stmt->close();
```

I tried using :

```
$rs = $stmt->get_result();
$arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// close statement
$stmt->close();
//store array into session
$_SESSION['user']= $arr;
```

but I received a Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result().  I have php 5.3.8 and MySQL 5.1.70-cll running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::get_result` is only available if you are running the MySQL native driver (`mysqlnd`).

This is documented in [the manual page for the method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.get-result-mysqlnd).

---

To clarify:

There are three ways of accessing a MySQL database from PHP: the ancient `mysql` functions, the modern `mysqli` functions/class, and the `PDO` `mysql` extension.

All three of these interact with the database in the same way, using the library called `libmysqlclient`. Properly speaking, this is not part of PHP. It is a C library, which PHP uses.

In PHP 5.3, however, the `mysqlnd` driver was introduced. This is a native part of PHP (that's what the `n` stands for). In 5.3, it needs to be installed deliberately. From 5.4, it is the default way to access MySQL.

So to get it working, either install PHP 5.4 or compile PHP 5.3 with the options given in the [installation page for `mysqlnd`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php).

In the meantime, your method is probably the best to get the data. The only other way would be to use PDO instead, which might offer a nicer syntax. This, for instance, would be possible:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,user,pass,email,timezone,lastIP,currIP,dtLastLogin,dtCurrLogin FROM test_users WHERE user = :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->execute();

$_SESSION['user'] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I looked into that and it should be enabled by default based on my version.  I just looked at my php.ini though and find zero reference of it.

Comment: @user756659 `mysqlnd` is only enabled by default from 5.4. The method is available from 5.3, but only if the driver is installed. The only reason this method would be unavailable would be if it isn't enabled.

Comment: I have the mysqli extension installed - just verified through easy apache settings. Does this not add the driver?  All other mysqli functions I am using work perfectly fine.

Comment: @user756659 `mysqlnd` is *not* the `mysqli` extension.

Comment: I see what you are saying now.  I would need to update php. With that said, is there a way to accomplish the same result without using get_result?

Comment: Just installed 5.4.21 and still getting 'Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()'

Comment: @user756659 Just to confirm, can you run `echo phpversion();`

Comment: 5.4.21 returned.  Installed with easy apache and then restarted apache for good measure afterwards.

Comment: @user756659 I'm sorry, then: I'm stumped.

Comment: Well, thanks... I guess I will keep looking for info or maybe someone else can chime in.